# Merge statement optimization

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a two tables in SQL Server, in which one is the source for a MERGE operation into another.

The source table has 30Mil Records

The Target table has 180Mil Records.  Both tables have 227 columns.

I do have SSIS, but I'm told in this case, a MERGE statement is the better option.  Below is a shortened version of it:

```
;WITH MySource as (
    SELECT * FROM [STAGE].[dbo].[STAGE_TABLE]
)
MERGE [EDW].[dbo].[TARGET_TABLE] AS MyTarget
USING MySource
     ON MySource.[ID_FIELD] = MyTarget.[ID_FIELD]
    AND MySource.[LoadDate] >= MyTarget.[LoadDate]
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET 
     <<Target Column>> = MySource.<<Source Colums>> --227 columns
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT
    (
        [ID_FIELD], 
        [LoadDate], 
       <<225 Other Columns>>
    )
    VALUES (
        MySource.[ID_FIELD], 
        MySource.[LoadDate], 
        MySource.<<225 other columns>>
    );
```

The only changes I made to the script above is truncating the list of columns to keep the code block here short.

My Problem is that I am getting hung on the execution. The profile screen shows a `CXPACKET` suspension with the error: `cwaitpipenewrow, node=2`.

How do I troubleshoot this?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like CXPACKET and suspended state means that some threads which have completed are logging that other thread's state which have not completed yet.
Please check here. The query need to update upto 1 Billion values in the table. hence it would be slow running queries.

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/96346/cxpacket-suspended-and-null-wait-type

https://www.sqlshack.com/troubleshooting-the-cxpacket-wait-type-in-sql-server/

Hope these articles might help you debug.